# How to remove profile image on YouTube on Google Apps account with Google+ turned off?

Tags: google-account, profile-picture

My daughters friend has a profile image on her Google Apps account from school, but wants none. It is already turned off in mail, but certain Google Apps use profile image from somewhere else, still the old image.

In YouTube when clicking change on image, it goes to a page saying Google plus is turned off for that organisation. Maybe it was turned on in the beginning. Hangouts also problem.

How to remove the profile image from everywhere?